# to load the data when application starts in ipad

Tags: ipad

I noticed that in iPad, the program does not initialize when we open an application. It is like the application is restored from the state when we closed the application. Could any one please inform me What should I do to call a method each time I start the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your application is not actually quit when it is minimized.

In the Xcode project navigator (on the left), click on your project (top). In the main area, choose your app under Targets. On the top, choose "info". Add a line, "Application does not run in background" and set its value to YES.

[image]

This will make your application quit completely when the home button is pressed.