# iPhone home button pressed

Tags: iphone, home-button

In my app has a button that opens the browser and my application was for background. I just want to close the app when the home button is clicked.

Comment: As I was saying earlier: Why is this important to you? As an interesting issue: You don't know *why* the home button is being pressed; it might be to leave your application; but it might also very well be to jump out quickly to turn on an internet radio player or similar. Maintain state; for 99 users out of a 100 it's the Right Thing™

Comment: please rephrase you question, it's really difficult to understand!

Comment: Same question as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625134/iphone-identify-home-button-pressed) ?

Comment: Theres times when you want to do it for security reasons. (Enterprise apps mainly). Please don't down vote based on the fact YOU don't see a point to it. Note: you CAN downvote b/c the question has been asked about 1000 times.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you want your app to quit (rather than going to the background), you'll have to set the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key in your Info.plist to `YES`.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked and answered many times. I just answered it a few hours ago:

[to load the data when application starts in ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623033/to-load-the-data-when-application-starts-in-ipad/6623156#6623156)